# Show more / Show less Jquery code working on fiddle but not in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this code i found on fiddle.

[Original Fiddle Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3VTb7/)

But when I use it in my website it does not work.  I found this possible solution

[Code is Working on Fiddle but not on Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353535/code-is-working-on-fiddle-but-not-on-website)

But it either did not work for my case, or I implemented it incorrectly. I'm very new so neither would surprise me. Thank you in advance for the help!

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 100);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 100);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
div.text-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;    
}

.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;        
}
p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.show-more {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    width:200px;
    border: solid 1px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
   
</div>

<table class="flat-table flat-table-1" width="100%">

<tr style="background-color:#FFF;">
    <td class="table-head">Name</td>
    <td class="table-head">Review</td>
    <td class="table-head">Rating</td>
</tr>
    
<tr>
    <td class="name">John Doe</td>
    <td class="review"> <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div></td>
    <td class="rating">5</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="name">John Doe</td>
    <td class="review"> <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div></td>
    <td class="rating">5</td>
</tr>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a Jquery extension.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the fiddle has jquery as well as the jquery ui extension. All you need to do is add

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

in your html after importing JQuery.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 100);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 100);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
div.text-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;    
}

.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;        
}
p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.show-more {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    width:200px;
    border: solid 1px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
   
</div>

<table class="flat-table flat-table-1" width="100%">

<tr style="background-color:#FFF;">
    <td class="table-head">Name</td>
    <td class="table-head">Review</td>
    <td class="table-head">Rating</td>
</tr>
    
<tr>
    <td class="name">John Doe</td>
    <td class="review"> <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div></td>
    <td class="rating">5</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="name">John Doe</td>
    <td class="review"> <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div></td>
    <td class="rating">5</td>
</tr>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

switchClass() method is available only in jQuery UI, not present in jQuery. 
jQuery UI 1.8.18 is included in the fiddle code and missing in yours. 
Try including in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.